# Post data in array cloud firestore

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

Am working on an array to store multiple map location in an array using `geopoint`. Have a `location:geopoint` that accepts latitude and longitude, which are stored in an array. Cloud firestore only has `set` for creating new document `update` update existing document and `add` which have tried to add new geopoint to the array but it doesn't work.
How can I add new location while maintaining the previous data?

Comment: I don't think its a good idea to keep a growing array(list) inside a document. Instead you can create a `Subcollection` and `add` each location with a timestamp, later you can fetch it with the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Firestore doesn't currently have an "append an element to an array" kind of operation. For now, your best options are to either:

1. Override the existing array with a new array that contains all of the old data as before, plus the new data
2. Add this new geopoint into a map field instead (The things that look like little JSON-y objects).
3. Add every new geopoint as a new document in a subcollection.

Your implementation might depend on how many of these different geopoints you're planning on creating, and how you plan on querying them. If you're creating only a handful and want to get all of them back when you're grabbing the associated document, I'd go with one of the first two options. If you're planning on creating lots of geopoints and, say, want to only grab the 3 most recent, I'd go with the third option.